# Active Jdbc Association not work

Tags: java, jdbc

Olá. Tenho duas classes: Usuario e Competencia. Preciso fazer um relacionamento entre as duas, conforme abaixo:

```
public class User extends Model{

}

@Table(value = "competencias")
@BelongsTo(foreignKeyName = "user_id", parent = User.class)  
public class Competencia extends Model{

}

CREATE TABLE users(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('operadores_id_seq'::regclass),
  nome character varying(25) NOT NULL,
  nome_completo character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  senha character varying(120) NOT NULL,
  nivel integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 4,
  ativo boolean,
  created_at date DEFAULT now()
)

CREATE TABLE competencias(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('competencias_id_seq'::regclass),
  mes CHARACTER(2) NOT NULL,
  ano CHARACTER(4) NOT NULL,
  created_at DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ativo BOOLEAN,
  CONSTRAINT fk_competencia_operador FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Ao comandar a gravação do relacionamento na tabela Competencias, recebo o erro abaixo:

```
competencia.add(user);

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.javalite.activejdbc.associations.NotAssociatedException: No association from table 'competencias' to table 'users'
```

Comment: Traduz sua pergunta colega. Aqui é BR!

Comment: Perdão, é que havia postado no activelite.io e o Igor Polevoy pediu para colar aqui. Mas está bem simples, não vejo dificuldade em entender.

Comment: @LucianoBezerra Mesmo que seja fácil de entender, o [pt.so] é um site para lusófonos, sua pergunta deve estar em português. Caso prefira deixar em inglês, poste no [so].

Comment: Aliás, o problema é que você esqueceu de criar a ForeignKey.

Comment: Eu criei, só esqueci de colar o código:

    CONSTRAINT fk_competencia_operador FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES public.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION

Comment: foreignKeyName = "user_id"
CONSTRAINT **fk_competencia_operador** FOREIGN KEY (user_id)

Seria isso o erro?